# How to use ffmpeg to rip part of a VOB file

Tags: video, conversion, ffmpeg, ripping

I want to convert a VOB file to another video format using ffmpeg. The video that I'm interested in is found in the first half of the VOB file. Is there a way to convert only the part that I'm interested in, or at least just the first half of the VOB, so that I don't have to convert the whole file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Handbrake. It's a wrapper for ffmpeg that makes everything easy. It also has a cli version for batching.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can...`ffmpeg -sameq -ss [start_seconds] -t [duration_seconds] -i [input_file] [outputfile]`

Comment: What about the audio?

Comment: just add -acodec copy in the options

Comment: Please don't use `-sameq`: [What is the “sameq” or “same_quant” option in FFmpeg? Does it mean “same quality”?](http://superuser.com/questions/478549/what-is-the-sameq-or-same-quant-option-in-ffmpeg-does-it-mean-same-quality) – also, `-t` is an output option and needs to be specified after the input. Your command will not work with any recent ffmpeg versions.